# Getting error with sql query using python

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

**i am trying to fetch the list of sql query running more than 3600 sec and kill those id's  using python below is the code**

```
import json
import mysql.connector
import pymysql


def main():
    # TODO implement
    connection = pymysql.connect(user='', password='',
                                 host='',
                                 port=3306,
                                 database='');
    cursor = connection.cursor()  # get the cursor
    # cursor.execute('SHOW PROCESSLIST;')
    # extracted_data = cursor.fetchall();
    # for i in extracted_data:
    #     print(i)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        print(cursor.execute('SHOW PROCESSLIST'))
        for item in cursor.fetchall():
            if item.get('Time') > 3600 and item.get('command') == 'query':
                _id = item.get('Id')
                print('kill %s' % item)
                cursor.execute('kill %s', _id)
        connection.close()


main()
```

below is the error i am getting

```
"C:\drive c\pyfile\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/drive c/pyfile/sqlnew2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\drive c\pyfile\sqlnew2.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\drive c\pyfile\sqlnew2.py", line 18, in main
    if item.get('Time') > 3600 and item.get('command') == 'query':
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

The .fetchall() method returns a tuple, not a dictionary. Therefore you should access the elements using the numerical indexes, for example `item[0], item[1]`, etc

As an alternative, if you want to fetch the results as a dictionary, you can use a DictCursor

First import it:

```
import pymysql.cursors
```

Then modify the cursor line like that:

```
with connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
    ...
```

Comment: This error is resolved, but the print statement - print(cursor.execute('SHOW PROCESSLIST')) is not pritnting the process list in the output and not even if item.get('Time') > 3600 and item.get('command') == 'query': is working i guess below is the output i am getting it should return the process list and kill command should also return something.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"C:\drive c\pyfile\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/drive c/pyfile/sqlnew2.py"
9

Process finished with exit code 0